# Reference not found after switching from Debug to Release mode

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with several references in my VB.NET project.

For example I have this line of code:

```
Dim m As New Chilkat.Email
```

It comes from the library "ChilkatDotNet45.dll".

When I click on "References" and locate this dll, I can see that it has the settings "Use local copy" and "Do not include interop types".

When I switch to Release mode, the compiler tells me that "Chilkat.EMail" is not defined.

I have this problem with several DLLs, so it is not specific to Chilkat.

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you build a simplified project which has this problem and post a link here? We could then try switching Debug to Release on our machines and see if the we can reproduce.

Comment: Thank you so much! While I created a sample project, I noticed that the .DLL was put into my Debug folder by VS. I have removed the reference and added it again. That fixed my problem. Perhaps you can form this into a reply? I don't really know what happened there, and why the reference path is now the original path, and before it was my Debug folder.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I posted my idea as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the standard approaches to solving any programming-related issue is trying to reduce the scope of the investigation. If you have a big project, in which something doesn't work, try to create a smaller project, and try to replicate desired functionality in it. Reduce as much as possible, down to a brand new project with maybe 5-10 lines of code in it.

If you were unable to solve your problem after making a reduced test case, now it's good time to post it on StackOverflow. I am usually reducing problems **while** writing a question on SO (not before, as one might think), constantly thinking "ok, is it minimized enough"; and this is how 90% of the questions never get posted - I often find a solution along the way of reducing my question to bare bones. :)

In your case, can you build a simplified project which has this problem and post a link here? We could then try switching Debug to Release on our machines and see if the we can reproduce. There are too many options to do the guesswork.